# Passing a checkbox value to a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I am using C# on Winforms to populate a datagridview from a class in a library.  I have been able to get the datagridview to populate with all of my SQL Server data using a stored procedure.

I wish to allow the end user to modify the cells in the datagridview, which will update the SQL Server table through a second stored procedure. However, I cannot seem to get the checkbox value to be recognized once the update procedure is called.

My update query is as follows:

```
public void UpdateEmployee(int empID, string initials, string firstName, string lastName, int active)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DatabaseConnection.Database))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "UpdateEmployee";

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", empID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Initials", initials);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Acvite", active);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

After creating an instance of the library class, I was trying to call the `Update` method with this line of code:

```
empData.UpdateEmployee(Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1[0, e.RowIndex].Value),  // EmpID
        dataGridView1[1, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(), //Initials
        dataGridView1[2, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(), //FirstName
        dataGridView1[3, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString(), //LastName
        Convert.ToInt16(dataGridView1[4, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue)); // Active checkbox
```

I am getting an error stating that `@Active` has not been provided.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: You're getting the error because you misspelled `@Active`.  But more importantly, [can we please stop using `AddWithValue()`, already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: @Siyual I agree but in this case it shouldn't be a big deal. The datatypes are specified in the parameters because they are using a stored procedure.

Comment: Is there a disadvantage to using AddWithValue()?

Comment: @Siyual - please feel free to send me a link to a web site on alternatives to AddWithValue(). I was just taught this method and I welcome better ways.

Comment: @Wurm The link in my first comment explains the downfalls and alternatives.

Comment: I have edited my code, just so you wouldn't lose sleep tonight, @Siyual.  Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Acvite", active);
```

Spelling error? Active not Acvite?

Comment: That did get rid of that error, but the update isn't working :(

Comment: And thank you so much for seeing that!  I cannot believe i didn't see that before.

Comment: I have it working, now!  Thank you all for the fast replies!  I ended up calling the update method from the CellEndEdit event.  :0)